# How to see module load address in watch window?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to make the watch window display a loaded module's load address (the one you see in the "Modules" window) in MSVS 2012?

I find it tedious to copy the whole line and extract the address I need every time I start the program.

Answer (score 0):

I set a breakpoint on the dll entry point (new breakpoint -> `{,,<dll name>}DllMain`).

I then calculated the offset of current value of the stack pointer (`*rsp`) from the module load address (call this offset x).

For each subsequent run, you can add a value in the watch (`value of rsp - calculated x`) which will be the module load address when the dll entry point breakpoint is hit.